# Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleTicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I call a jQuery function, the error is displayed:
Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleTicker is not a function

I've tried to change $ per jQuery but nothing solves it.

This is my jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.simpleTicker($("#breakingNewsTicker"), {
        speed: 1000,
        delay: 3000,
        easing: 'swing',
        effectType: 'roll'
    });
    $.simpleTicker($("#internationalTicker"), {
        speed: 1000,
        delay: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        effectType: 'roll'
    });

})(jQuery);

! function(e) {
    e.simpleTicker = function(t, i) {
        var s = {
                speed: 1e3,
                delay: 3e3,
                easing: "swing",
                effectType: "slide"
            },
            n = {
                ul: "",
                li: "",
                initList: "",
                ulWidth: "",
                liHeight: "",
                tickerHook: "tickerHook",
                effect: {}
            },
            c = this;
        c.settings = {};
        e(t), t = t;
        c.init = function() {
            switch (c.settings = e.extend({}, s, i), n.ul = t.children("ul"), n.li = t.find("li"), n.initList = t.find("li:first"), n.ulWidth = n.ul.width(), n.liHeight = n.li.height(), t.css({
                height: n.liHeight
            }), n.li.css({
                top: "0",
                left: "0",
                position: "absolute"
            }), c.settings.effectType) {
                case "fade":
                    c.effect.fade();
                    break;
                case "roll":
                    c.effect.roll();
                    break;
                case "slide":
                    c.effect.slide()
            }
            c.effect.exec()
        }, c.effect = {}, c.effect.exec = function() {
            n.initList.css(n.effect.init.css).animate(n.effect.init.animate, c.settings.speed, c.settings.easing).addClass(n.tickerHook), t.find(n.li).length > 1 && setInterval(function() {
                t.find("." + n.tickerHook).animate(n.effect.start.animate, c.settings.speed, c.settings.easing).next().css(n.effect.next.css).animate(n.effect.next.animate, c.settings.speed, c.settings.easing).addClass(n.tickerHook).end().appendTo(n.ul).css(n.effect.end.css).removeClass(n.tickerHook)
            }, c.settings.delay)
        }, c.effect.fade = function() {
            n.effect = {
                init: {
                    css: {
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        opacity: "1",
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                },
                start: {
                    animate: {
                        opacity: "0"
                    }
                },
                next: {
                    css: {
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0",
                        zIndex: "99"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        opacity: "1"
                    }
                },
                end: {
                    css: {
                        display: "none",
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, c.effect.roll = function() {
            n.effect = {
                init: {
                    css: {
                        top: "3em",
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        top: "0",
                        opacity: "1",
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                },
                start: {
                    animate: {
                        top: "-3em",
                        opacity: "0"
                    }
                },
                next: {
                    css: {
                        top: "3em",
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0",
                        zIndex: "99"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        top: "0",
                        opacity: "1"
                    }
                },
                end: {
                    css: {
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, c.effect.slide = function() {
            n.effect = {
                init: {
                    css: {
                        left: 200,
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        left: "0",
                        opacity: "1",
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                },
                start: {
                    animate: {
                        left: -200,
                        opacity: "0"
                    }
                },
                next: {
                    css: {
                        left: n.ulWidth,
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: "0",
                        zIndex: "99"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        left: "0",
                        opacity: "1"
                    }
                },
                end: {
                    css: {
                        zIndex: "98"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, c.init()
    }, e.fn.simpleTicker = function(t) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (void 0 == e(this).data("simpleTicker")) {
                var i = new e.simpleTiecker(this, t);
                e(this).data("simpleTicker", i)
            }
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```

And this, is my HTML:

```
<div class="breaking-news-area d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="news-title">
        <p>Velho Gaúcho</p>
    </div>
    <div id="breakingNewsTicker" class="ticker">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/newsportal-js/plugins/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/newsportal-js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/newsportal-js/active.js"></script>
```

The jQuery code I removed from a project with jQuery version 2, and in the current project I'm using version 3.
Can this be the problem?

Comment: I don't see the `simpleTicker` script in the code. Can you show where u have added it ?

Comment: @Panther Sorry, I edited.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use your `simpleTicker` plugin before it has been added to jQuery. Try moving your first IIFE **below** the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add simpleTicker plugin JS and css files. Your code sees

```
$.simpleTicker
```

as built-in function. it should be something like this:

```
<link href="jquery.simpleTicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then js file

```
<script src="jquery.simpleTicker.js"></script>
```